# Updating syntax

Tags: sql-server

I have the following scenario:

Table is `_etblpricelistprices`

Columns are as follows:

```
iPriceListNameID    iPricelistNameID   iStockID   fExclPrice

1                   1                  1           10
2                   2                  1           20
3                   3                  1           30
4                   4                  1           40
5                   5                  1           100
6                   6                  1           200
7                   7                  1           300
8                   8                  1           400
9                   1                  2           1000
10                  2                  2           2000
11                  3                  2           3000
12                  4                  2           4000
13                  5                  2           50
14                  6                  2           40
15                  7                  2           30
16                  8                  2           20
```

There are only two stock items here, but a lot more in the DB. The first column is the PK which auto-increments. The second column is the `Pricelist`. The `pricelist` is split as follows. (1-4) is current pricing and (5-8) is future pricing. the third column is the stock item's ID, and the fourth column, the pricing of the item.

I need a script to update this table to swap the future and current pricing per item.  Please help

Comment: seems my formatting is out. please ask if you need the layout, and I will gladly mail it to you

Comment: Do you mean that pricelist 1 and pricelist 5 values should swap places, ditto for 2 with 6, 3 with 7 and 4 with 8? If not, I'm not sure what you mean, you'll need to explain more.

Comment: Yes Damien, that is it exactly, but it needs to do so per stockid

Comment: Do the first and second columns really have those names, only different by case? If not, could you edit your question and correct the names?

Comment: these are the columns in the db yes, unfortunately.  the first comlumn is the pk, and autoincrements for each new stock item that will be added into the system.  the second column is the pricelistid which will only go from 1-8.  I can get the values to swap when there is only 1 stock item in the system by running the following syntax, but when there is more than one stock item, it is failing.

Comment: update _etblPriceListPrices set fExclPrice = (select fExclPrice from futuretemp
 where IDPriceListPrices = '6') where IDPriceListPrices = '2'

I created a temp table with all the info from the _etblpricelistprices table

Answer (score 0):

Observe, if you will, that swapping the `iPricelistNameID` values will achieve the *same* overall effect as swapping the `fExclPrice` values, and can be perfomed using a formula:

```
UPDATE _etblpricelistprices
SET
    iPricelistNameID = CASE
                WHEN iPricelistNameID > 4 THEN iPricelistNameID - 4
                ELSE iPricelistNameID + 4
    END
```